# problems compiling etcher fork using electron-builder

Tags: electron, cross-compiling, electron-builder

I've built an [Etcher](https://github.com/resin-io/etcher) fork, and I'm having trouble generating a working windows build.

their documentation mentions `make electron-installer-zip` and `make electron-installer-nsis` as make targets; however, these entries do not exist in the supplied `Makefile`.

I've thus reverted to using `electron-builder`, which works great for generating a linux executable / installer.

However, my fork is intended to run primarily on windows;

After resolving various dependency issues, I've successfully built a non-working windows portable `.exe` using the following command:

`node_modules/.bin/electron-builder --platform win portable --arch ia32`.

**however, when running the etcher.exe file, I get the notorious `%1 is not a win32 application` error**.

More specifically, I get this error with the module `lzma-native`, with the file `node_modules\lzma-native\binding\lzma_native.node`.

on ubuntu 16.04, running `file ....lzma_native.node` claims this is a 32-bit LSB shared object.

Compiling through a windows VM was even worse, but I do have access to a Windows machine if that's necessary

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Etcher doesn't currently support cross-compiling (found this important bit of information in a commented out section in the Makefile). I'm guessing some of the environment variables were being manipulated by Etcher.

After a lot of trial and error, I've successfully built the fork under windows 10.